# Problem creating objects, class could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my `bllLanguage.cs` class I am not able to create `dalLanguage` class's objects and vice versa. It says `dalLanguage.cs`/`bllLanguage.cs` could not be found.
Whats wrong with the code below?

**bllLanguage.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Proj2;


namespace Proj2.BLL.Main.Setting
{
    public class bllLanguage
    {

        public bllLanguage()
        { 
        //add constructor code here
        }

        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Properties
        /// </summary>
        private int intLanguageID;
        private string strDescription;
        private string strValue;

        #endregion

        public int LanguageID
        {
            get { return intLanguageID; }
            set { intLanguageID = value; }
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get { return strDescription; }
            set { strDescription = value; }
        }
        public string Value
        {
            get { return strValue; }
            set { strValue = value; }
        }

        #region getLanguage
        /// <summary>
        /// getLanguage
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataSet getLanguage()
        {


            dalLanguage objdalLanguage = new dalLanguage(); // ERROR HERE
            DataSet dsgetLanguage = objdalLanguage.getLanguage();
            return dsgetLanguage;

        }
        #endregion




    }
}
```

**dalLanguage.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Proj2;

namespace Proj2.DAL.Main.Setting
{
   public class dalLanguage
    {
        public dalLanguage()
        { 
        //constructor code here
        }


        #region getLanguage
        /// <summary>
        /// getLanguage
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataSet getLanguage()
        {
            DataSet dsgetLanguage = new DataSet();
            try
            {

                dsgetLanguage = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Constants.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[Main].[sp_getLanguage]");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return dsgetLanguage;
        }
        #endregion



    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe post the _exact_ error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the namespaces do not match

```
Proj2.BLL.Main.Setting
Proj2.DAL.Main.Setting
```

you need to specify the fully qualified name or import the namespaces. importing Proj2 only is not enough

Answer (score 1):

First thing I noticed is that you lack using statement in bllLanguage.cs. add

```
using Proj2.DAL.Main.Setting;
```

in bllLanguage.cs

Comment: but it does contain this statement using Proj2;
 Why wont it find that dal class then ?

Answer (score 1):

First of never write

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

*Throw ex will overwrite the stacktrace!*

Write just throw if you want to re throw the exception.

Question are they in the same project and if not do they have a reference to the other project?